# Create a Regular expression using the gi flags from a variable

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var metin = "baris";
var icerikoku = "Hello Baris. What is surname Baris. Bye bye baris. How are you metin.";
var n = icerikoku.replace(/metin/gi, "ziya");
$("#icerikoku").html(n);
```

**print:**
  `Hello Baris. What is surname Baris. Bye bye baris. How are you ziya.`

**but, must be:**
  `Hello ziya. What is surname ziya. Bye bye ziya. How are you metin.`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/) constructor for that:

```
var n = icerikoku.replace(new RegExp(metin, 'gi'), "ziya");
```

This will allow you to pass variables to your regexp.

Comment: @baris if my answer was helpfull to you don't forget to accept it. And welcome to SO ;)